# how to change from a list of strings to a list of pointers to strings

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to get this to return a string, but i am having trouble getting it working.  The goal is to have a doubly-linked list that points to strings.  I am not allowed to have it contain the string, it must point to it instead.  Currently i am having trouble getting my program to use it.  For example, it always seems to return what the command was, and its confusing me and hard to explain.

```
#ifndef DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_H
#define DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "Playlist.h"

using namespace std;

class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    DoublyLinkedList();
    ~DoublyLinkedList();
    bool empty();
    void append(string& s);
    void insertBefore(string& s);
    void insertAfter(string& s);
    void remove(string& s);
    void begin();
    void end();
    bool next();
    bool prev();
    bool find(string& s);
    const string& getData();
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node (string *data, Node *next, Node *prev)
        {m_data = data; m_next = next; m_prev = prev;}
        string *m_data;
        Node * m_next;
        Node * m_prev;
    };
    Node *m_head;
    Node *m_tail;
    Node *m_current;
};
#endif // DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

.cpp file>>>>

```
const string& DoublyLinkedList::getData()
{
    string *m_tmp;
    m_tmp = m_current->m_data;
    cout << m_current->m_data << endl;
    //cout << "returning: " << m_current->m_data << endl;
   // return m_current->m_data;
   return *m_tmp;
}

void DoublyLinkedList::append(string &s)
{
    if (!m_head)
    {
        m_head = new Node(&s, NULL, NULL);
        m_tail = m_head;
        m_current = m_head;
    }
    else
    {
        m_tail->m_next = new Node (&s, NULL, m_tail);
        m_tail = m_tail->m_next;
        m_current = m_tail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: **First:** You have to implement your own linked-lists  (That is, its an exercise/homework to learn about programming), or you can use implemented cointainers like which are provided by the standard library?  **Second:** The pointers of the second list have to point to the strings of the first list, in other words, the second list is used to share the ownership of the first list of strings?

Comment: I have to implement my own linked list, it is a doubly linked list that has a next, prev, and a pointer to a string.

Comment: And the second question?

Comment: i wasnt sure how to answer that.

Comment: I think what Manu343726 is referring to is that a "list with pointers" can either point to an object "owned by the list", or point to an object that was created and belongs to some entity OUTSIDE of the list. This affects the "rules" for how the object in the linked list is created and destroyed and "how you use" the linked list and the content in there. If the string belongs to something outside the list, then it may change at times without the list knowing about it. If it is completey "owned" by the list, then the list is responsible for the content...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void store_value(vector<string*>& vec, string& str)
{
  vec.push_back(&str);
}

void create_and_store_value(vector<string*>& vec)
{
  string str("This string is temporary");
  store_value(vec, str);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  vector<string*> pointers;

  create_and_store_value(pointers);
  cout << *pointers.back() << endl;

  string myPersistingString("Yay");
  store_value(pointers, myPersistingString);
  cout << *pointers.back() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This example contains two function, a function `store_value` which behaves similar to your `append` function (except, for the purposes of this example working on a `std::vector`) and a second function showing the possible danger of taking the address of a reference (this is one of the possible hazards that I believe Manu343726 and Mats Petersson are preluding too).

The reason this is dangerous is because the string declared inside `create_and_store_value` does not persist after the completion of the function.  This means that we are left with a pointer to memory which is probably not what we expect.  On the other hand, creating a string inside the `main` function is fine, since the string there persists until the end of the program.

For us to help you further, I would suggest editing your question to give us an example of how you are calling your function.  I would suggest pasting a minimal striped down version of your code including an example of how you are calling append, something like:

```
#include <blah>

class DoubleLinkedList
{
    DoubleLinkedList(void)
    {
        // Include these inline to make copying and pasting simpler.
    }

    ~DoubleLinkedList(void)
    {
        ...
    }

    append(...) { ... }
    getData(...) { ... }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DoubleLinkedList dll;

    // Show us how you are using this list

    return 0;
}
```

In the above, replace the comments and dots with the relevant code.